# Laravel 5.1 Mockery expectation ignored while testing controller

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1, mockery

I have a Controller depending on a UserManager. This is the controller constructor:

```
public function __construct(UserManager $manager) {
    $this->manager = $manager;
}
```

This is the test code.

```
public function test_something() {
    $this->withoutMiddleware();

    // Setup Input.
    $user = ['email' => 'foo@bar.baz', 'password' => 'pass', 'accessLevel' => 'admin'];

    // Setup expectations.
    $mock = \Mockery::mock("Users\UserManager")->shouldReceive('foo');

    // Bind to container... not sure whether this is needed.
    $this->app->instance("Users\UserManager", $mock);

    // Call action.
    $this->call('POST', 'api/v1/temp/users', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

I set the expectation on the `foo` method, which doesn't exists and therefore is not invoked anywhere, however my test won't fail.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify how many times the `foo` method should be called:

```
->shouldReceive('foo')->once();
```

Make sure that you also have a `tearDown` method where you reset Mockery or it won't work:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    Mockery::close();
}
```

Comment: Whoops missed that! Thank you mate.